# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute how to use for logger (c#)

Tags: c#, logging, actionfilterattribute

I have class:

```
 public class GeoSalesLogger : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
       private Stopwatch timer;
       private Request Argument;

    public ILogger logger { get; set; }

    public GeoSalesLogger()
    {
    }

    public GeoSalesLogger(ILogger<GeoSalesLogger> logger)
    {
        logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){}
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext){}
  }
```

Next I call in ather classes [GeoSalesLogger]

Question: how can I add ILogger here, because I can't add it in constructor. Also I try to use autofuc

```
builder.RegisterType<GeoLogger>();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

And

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogger>();
```

How can I take ILogger here without static?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the logger for the `ActionFilterAttribute` using the `ActionExecutingContext`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<GeoSalesLogger>>();
    ...
}
```